# How does VS Code show type errors for TypeScript if TypeScript needs to be compiled?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

TypeScript is a statically typed language, which means it validates types on compile and converts the code to plain JavaScript.

With that in mind, how does VS Code show me type errors if I have neither compiled nor ran my code?

Comment: The TypeScript extension does it behind the scenes...

Comment: It compiles the code, of course.

Comment: In short, there is a TypeScript _language service_, which runs in the background. It compiles and analyzes your code and provides type information and errors and warnings.

Comment: if C++ gets compiled to CPU Assembler how can VSC show C++ type errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VS Code's builtin TypeScript Language Features extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions/typescript-language-features) talks to a [tsserver](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Standalone-Server-(tsserver)). Quoting from the tsserver wiki:

> The TypeScript standalone server (aka `tsserver`) is a node executable that encapsulates the TypeScript compiler and language services, and exposes them through a JSON protocol. `tsserver` is well suited for editors and IDE support.

tsserver (using the TypeScript compiler itself) does the heavy lifting of all the TypeScript IntelliSense in VS Code.